# Delete historically locked "What good technology podcasts are out there?"

Tags: support, locked-posts, historical-lock

The question [What good technology podcasts are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there) was asked and set up as a community wiki in 2008, deleted in 2010, then undeleted and locked as a historical question in 2011. I would like to propose that it be deleted again, for good this time.

Eight years is a long time on the Internet. The vast majority of podcasts in the main list are no longer active; many of the links are broken, or at least no longer point to a podcast that's still being maintained. Historical locks are intended for off-topic questions which still have value to the site, but this question has nothing to offer beyond disappointment.

Comment: 8 out of 10 links that I clicked for "Windows/.NET" are still active...

Comment: You must have gotten really lucky. I checked all 18 links in that section. Five were active podcasts, four were inactive podcasts (no new shows in at least a year), and the other nine were either completely dead or didn't point to a podcast anymore. Other sections of the post are even worse.

Comment: *Stack Overflow (inactive, but still a good listen)* jeez, nuke that POS question, pls